# Web Services Testing Using Intellij or Eclipse Instead of SOAPUI

Tags: wsdl, automated-tests, integration-testing, soapui, web-api-testing

I'm working on multiple projects where most of them include SOAP services that i have been testing using SOAPUI open source, creating multiple linked steps, using groovy script and so on.

However when it comes to complicated TCs & reusing , it doesn't seem to be so efficient

So a colleague of mine suggested that we can generate WSDL client using any IDE like eclipse or intellj , and thus we will be able to invoke methods found in WSDL directly with a much more privileges & control.

My question is what can possibly go wrong with that, i believe there's a reason why SOAPUI have been around for so long and most commonly used tool when it comes to web services testing.

Comment: Look into importing and reusing the SoapUI jars in your IDE. That way you still use the SoapUI paradigm, but in a more powerful ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little biased, but after using soapUI for 10+ years, I haven't found many web service test cases that it isn't able to handle, from simple calls to complex orchestrations and validations involving both REST and SOAP services. But, like any comprehensive tool, it takes time and effort and some trial and error to become proficient in its use. It also has some quirks and annoyances, but less than most of the tools in my development toolkit IMHO.

See the [soapUI tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/soapui/info) for some resources that may help get the most out of soapUI.

It you've reached the limits of OSS soapUI, try the paid version: soapUI Pro/Ready API. The additional feature set is significant, including better support for reusing Groovy scripts and a script editor that some intellisense to help write code.

I would fully exhaust the the capabilities of soapUI and soapUI Pro before I would remotely consider trying to write my own web service client.